# TFS Reporting, FactBuildProject and FactBuildDetails empty

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, tfs-reports

I'm using TFS 2015 on-prem and I'm using the standard SCRUM template. I have 1 Team Project and I'm using the team field to segregate work. I have created a few build definitions and ran a few builds over the last few weeks.

When I installed TFS I did not install or configure Reporting Services straight away as I had planned to do that later. I have since done this and I now have my Tfs_Warehouse which is updating with most things but NOT FactBuildProject or FactBuildDetails. Some of my other facts are pulling over, such as FactCurrentWorkItem and even FactBuildCoverage. I have rebuilt the warehouse in the TFS Admin Console.

As this is a standard process template and standard reports I expect that the required fields should be set to reportable.

How can I get data in my FactBuildProject table and where can I look for issues with it? I'm not sure where to start and I can't find anyone else in the world with a similar problem.

Comment: Are you using the new task-based build system or the old XAML builds?

Comment: Yep, the new task-based and I like it. Unfortunately I have read Mikaels answer :( I'll have to think of a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new task-based build system, then you are out of luck, since that data is not being propagated to the data warehouse.

Check the comments on this blogpost: http://nakedalm.com/create-a-build-vnext-build-definition-on-vso/

Comment: Yep, afraid so. Darn, that's annoying. I'm not reverting back to XAML so I'll have to think of a workaround. Cheers